# Error while making a multiselect using vue-select

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-select

I am using vue-select in my project along with tabulator. I was able to fetch data from json file and view it. But when selecting the options i get an error saying "  Component emitted event "option:selecting" but it is neither declared in the emits option nor as an "onOption:selecting" prop. ". I could not resolve this error after multiple try. Below is the code.

```
 **<template>
      <form> 
          <div class="container h-25 w-10/12 mx-auto pb-3  border 2 border-gray-300 flex flex-col rounded-md items-left bg-gray-100" >     
              <label class="px-3 py-1 w-10/12 text-xs text-black font-medium">Employee</label> 
              <div class="px-2">
                   <v-select v-model="Selected" multiple :options="options" label="Employee"  placeholder="---SELECT---"  class="style-chooser"></v-select>
              </div>
              <!-- <span>Selected: {{ Employee_Id }}</span> -->                
           </div>
       </form>
       <!-- <ul><li v-for="item in datas" :key="item.Employee">{{ item.Employee }}</li></ul> -->
</template>
<script>
import dataset from './dataset.json'
    export default {
        data(){
                return {
                   
                    openCard: false,
                    Selected: ""
                        }
              },
              computed: {
                    options: () => dataset
                         },
              methods:{
              open(){
                this.openCard = ! this.openCard
                     },
             },
}
</script>**
```

Your help is highly appreciated la.

Comment: How did you install `vue-select`?  It looks like Vue 3 support is minimal  https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/1251

Comment: I have used the above mentioned link of GitHub branch. Read somewhere that it is compatible with vue3. I simply pulled this branch using node modules and till date it was working fine but when I used v-model for binding the selected data,  there I got the problem.